# Does the slug vomit charm create life?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

Where did the slugs that afflicted Ron come from when he was under the slug vomiting charm? Does the charm create life, or were the slugs plucked from somewhere else and placed inside Ron?

Comment: Pure speculation, but perhaps they only exist for a short time? cf. the bird charm Hermione uses on Ron in *Half-Blood Prince*.

Comment: @alexwlchan - Hermione didn't use the bird charm "on Ron" per se. She used "*Avis*" to conjure the birds without Ron there, and THEN used "*oppugno*" to sick them on Ron

Comment: Related question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8574/how-alive-are-animals-created-by-spells?rq=1

Comment: @BorhanMooz Thank you. I'd call my question a dup...

Comment: That questions' answer doesn't mention slugs though.

Comment: @DVK It doesn't; and that's why I left is as related. Although it does have an answer to the core issue, slugs are just more specific. And this question is newer...

Comment: It seems dupey to me. Slugs are animals therefore {Slugs} ⊂ {animals} therefore dupe.

Comment: I agree. Call this one a dupe. I VTC awhile  back. You guys need to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems a common thing in HP spells - *Avis* was used to conjure birds by Hermione and Ollivander, they [transfigured inanimate objects into animate - see full list on the Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aTransfiguration_Spells), Bat Bogey Hex was used to create bats from snot etc...

Also, spells were used to conjure/create flora - e.g. flowers to put on Harry's parents grave conjured by Hermione.

The canon was never very clear on whether this was life creation permanently, life creation temporarily, or transporting existing life from someplace else.

Comment: Alrighty then. The green check mark is now on hold.